# What are the practical applications of Centre of Mass & Centre of Gravity?

Tags: automotive-engineering, aerospace-engineering, aerodynamics, centre-of-gravity

I have learnt COM and COG are different things if we have non uniform gravitational field i.e. mass will be same at anywhere but gravity will be different. I want to find practical examples of both COM and COG if they are different.

Comment: Have a look at container ships.

Comment: Kindly explain. COG or COM?

Comment: IMHO, unless you are involved in engineering of space elevators or making ultra precise measurements there is little room for practical difference between COM and COG for a "average" engineer.

Comment: That concludes it is same whether we say COG or COM?

Answer (score 2):

Imagine you have 10,000 Km long bar. One end of it lies on the North pole and the other end lies near the equator. Now, since the gravity of the earth would be stronger near the pole than the equator (as proven by science), so it means that one half of the bar will be more heavy than the other. This asserts that the C.o.G will not lie exactly at the middle of the bar, but actually closer to that end which is on the pole.

On the other hand, C.o.M is still the same lying exactly at the middle of the bar.

For parctically possible objects, the C.o.G and C.o.M can be assumed to be lying on the same point since the gravitational fields don't change too much.

Comment: Surely COM and COG will be somewhere under the surface of the earth because of the curvature of the rod. I don't think this is a good example.

Comment: @Transistor, but the 2 would be in different spots.

Comment: ITs easier to think of a 10000 km high vertical pilar though

Answer (score 0):

one practical example would be the effect of the moon on the earth.

Moon pulls the side of the earth facing the moon a bit stronger than the far side so the CG of the earth with respect to the moon is not the same as the CM of the earth. This is the source of tides.

The CG of earth and moon lies 4671 km out of the earth CM, barycenter. They both rotate around this point.

[source](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Barycenter#:%7E:text=This%20is%20the%20case%20for,bodies%20will%20orbit%20around%20it.)